# How can I calculate Variance with two groups?

Tags: r

I am currently struggling with something probably quite simple, but somehow I am stuck.

I am evaluating an experiment. There are two groups: "narrow" and "wide". Both of the groups evaluated one sentence from a scale from 0-10, depending on the group they were in. A participant in the "narrow" condition only sees the "narrow satisfaction sentence", while a participant in the "wide" group only sees the "wide satisfaction sentence". This means, that each participant has an NA for the sentence they didn't see. 
Participant A got into the "narrow" group, which means in the column "narrow", there is his value 8. In the "wide" group his value is NA, since he didn't have to evaluate that sentence.

More precisely, here's some of my data:

> Condition__________Satisfaction_wide__________Satisfaction_narrow
>
> > wide_____________8______________________NA
> >
> > wide_____________7______________________NA
> >
> > narrow___________NA____________________9
> >
> > narrow___________NA____________________6
> >
> > wide_____________5______________________NA
> >
> > wide_____________3______________________NA
> >
> > narrow___________NA____________________7
> >
> > narrow___________NA____________________8

Now I want to compare the variances, but I am not quite sure how I can do that since I have NAs.

I have tried

`bartlett.test(data$Condition == "narrow" ~ data$Condition == "wide")`

but that gives me: NA.

I have also tried

```
var.test(data$Condition == "narrow" ~ data$Condition == "wide")
```

but that (obviously) also gives me NA.

How will I be able to tell R to make 2 groups and calculate the variance?I couldn't find anything similar on the internet or on this website, since they mostly deal with calculating variances without Nas.
 I am sorry for the formatting, I am a newbie to R and stackoverlow. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistical methods, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create two vectors, one for wide and one for narrow and remove the NA's in each. Then feed it to your function. Such as:
`wide <- data$Satisfaction_wide[[!is.na(data$Satisfation_wide) & Data$conditon =="wide"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sebastian!

I did it like this now:

```
data$Condition <- factor(data$Condition, labels = c("narrow", "wide"))
data$satisfaction <- rowSums(data[7:8], na.rm=T)
```

`tapply(data$satisfaction, data$Condition, sd, na.rm=T)`

```
bartlett.test(satisfaction ~ Condition, data = data)
```

works perfectly :)